# Python - Casting a float as int to be used as array index returns 0th element of the array

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, casting

I want to create a new array that has some sifted elements from an old array

This is what the array looks like:

```
print(freqs[0])
print(freqs[1])
print(freqs[2])
print(freqs[3])
print(freqs[4])

>>(-1.356524149576826+0j)
  (-1.5188337718697111-0.0028277787696928914j)
  (-1.537925820349816+0.02545857328595845j)
  (-1.7483732926022144+0.0875845050778933j)
  (-1.8506826888571075+0.16201185108446528j)
```

when I cast the index "manually" to troubleshoot it all works fine

```
print(int(0*scaler), freqs[int(0*scaler)])
print(int(1*scaler), freqs[int(1*scaler)])
print(int(2*scaler), freqs[int(2*scaler)])
print(int(3*scaler), freqs[int(3*scaler)])
print(int(4*scaler), freqs[int(4*scaler)])

>>0 (-1.356524149576826+0j)
  0 (-1.356524149576826+0j)
  1 (-1.5188337718697111-0.0028277787696928914j)
  2 (-1.537925820349816+0.02545857328595845j)
  3 (-1.7483732926022144+0.0875845050778933j)
```

However, once I put this kind of logic in a loop I always get the 0th element. And I doubled checked that my index variable is in fact an int

```
for i in range(length):
    index = int(i*scaler)

    if index < length:
    
        newfreqs[i] = freqs[index] 
        print(i,index,freqs[index])

>>0 0 (-1.356524149576826+0j)
  1 0 (-1.356524149576826+0j)
  2 1 (-1.356524149576826+0j)
  3 2 (-1.356524149576826+0j)
  4 3 (-1.356524149576826+0j)
```

I get the exact same behavior if I use math.floor() instead of int(). Oddly round() seems to work fine but it does not produce the correct index value I need. It is only an issue anywhere inside the loop, outside the loop it works as expected.

Here is the entire function

```
def reindex(freqs, halfSteps):
    scaler = halfStep**(-halfSteps)

    newfreqs = freqs
    length = len(newfreqs)
    
    for i in range(length):
        index = int(i*scaler)
        if index < length:
        
            newfreqs[i] = freqs[index] 
            print(i,index,freqs[index])
        
    return newfreqs
```

Comment: What are the values of `length` and `scaler`?

Comment: What you have posted in principle ought to work. You are doing something that you are not showing us, before the start of the loop. Print out the whole list `print(freqs)` before the loop.

Comment: I'd say it's pretty clear that `index` is OK but `freqs` somehow got changed so all the elements are the same.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that `freqs` has changed. In that last bit of code, `freqs[3]` is `-1.356524149576826+0j`. What type of data structure is `freqs` and what are those elements? Can you `print(freqs)` right after the loop to see if its the data you think it is?

Comment: What is `newfreqs`? Its an existing list. Is it just another alias to the list in `freq`? You could be overwriting the original array and since i is always >= index, after a few runs it would have bubbled the first element all the way up.

Comment: @Mark Ransom freqs did not change because if I put in a print statement that just has freqs[i], freqs[2*i] or any manipulation of i that does not need to be cast as integer it will print the correct value. I will put up the entirety of the function in my post

Comment: @tdelaney freqs is a ndarray of complex numbers thousands of elements long. It's not being manipulated because if I replace freqs[index] with freqs[i] for example and print it I will get the right values.

Comment: Exactly as I said, you're modifying `freqs` because `newfreqs` is the same object.  Use `newfreqs = freqs[:]` and you will make a copy, breaking the connection.

Comment: @Mark Ransom you are totally right, freqs does get changed every time the loop reaches the element of the index. Your suggestion of 'newfreqs = freqs[:]" did not change the behavior but I think if I just initialize the new array with zeros I will be ok. Thank you!!

Comment: numpy slicing doesn't behave like python lists. You get a view into the existing array so newfreqs changes would still show up in freqs. `freqs.copy()` is the better option for a duplicate array. That oddity has burned a lot of us! See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing

Comment: @MikhailKosyan - Its okay to answer your own question. You've got a solution in creating a new array.

Comment: @tdelaney I didn't realize this was a numpy array, the question makes no mention of it. 
 Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @MarkRansom - makes sense. Wasn't sure of the timeline. I think its worth keeping as a general FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the initialization of newfreq to 'zeros(len(freqs))'